# How to get purchase data with Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Is there any way to get the purchase data for iOS? Chen tipsed me that there is Display.getInstance().getProperty("lastPurchaseData") for Android, but i wonder if this works for iOS purchases too or if there is another way to access it?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the [wasPurchased](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/payment/Purchase.html#wasPurchased-java.lang.String-) API what you are looking for?

Comment: Not exactly, i need the purchase data to send to my backend server for verification, because the app gets "products" from the server.

Comment: Can't you just use the `paymentSucceeded` callback to update your server?

Comment: If i understand right the paymentSucceeded is for manual payments, not item purchases? I only got itemPurchased fired when I tested.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I just looked at the `lastPurchaseData` in the Android implementation which carries this comment: "This is a temp hack to get the last purchase raw data. The IAP API needs to be modified to support this on all platforms". I guess that answers the question https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/Android/src/com/codename1/impl/android/CodenameOneActivity.java#L139-L141 The JSON data will obviously be too different for iOS to make any meaningful common code, we need a better abstraction

Comment: For me it's enough if you add the raw JSON object in lastPurchaseData also for iOS. Even better would have been to have it as a parameter to itemPurchased, ie itemPurchased (sku, jsonResponse). Then I can send the entire object to the server for verification, or extract the platform-specific fields and send it as needed to the server.

Comment: iOS doesn't have that JSON AFAIK. This API is implemented natively so iOS's API's are in Objective-C and don't quite expose that.

Comment: I want to do like this:  http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-to-verify-apple-in-app-purchase-receipt-using-java I need to verify on the server side that a purchase is ok, otherwise unauthorized requests can be send to my server and get the protected data.

Comment: And here is Objective-C approach: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Comment: We have an issue in the tracker for iOS subscriptions scheduled for 3.5. So you can file an RFE on that. It might be possible to hack something here with native interfaces but I'm not sure.